# Can't see ros2 nodes over WiFi network

Tags: ros2, network

I am having a problem with my ROS2 network, I have both the robot computer and my personal computer connected to the same WiFi network, however If I launch the ROS 2 code on the robot and try to check the nodes and info on my personal computer, it doesn't show anything, if I check on the robot computer everything is working correctly, so I don't know what do I need to do, as far as I know, it is not necessary to set the environment variables as it was done in ROS, so I hope someone can give me some ideas about what could be the problem.

I have CycloneDDS installed and set up on both computers.

Thank you!

Comment: are you able to ping each computer?

Comment: Yes, I am able to ping each computer, and I am able to access the robot computer with SSH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue with the following setup :

- A Yocto distribution running ROS2 code on ROS_DOMAIN_ID=28, exposing a WIFI hotspot and connected to the internet using ethernet cable
- My computer connected to the WIFI hotspot and trying to access node list on ROS_DOMAIN_ID=28

In fact I solved the issue by removing the ethernet cable. It seems CycloneDDS chose to work on ethernet network instead of the local network created by this hotspot. I don't know if you are in the same conditions.

And of course if you want to solve it forever, checkout the cyclonedds documentation on how to select a specific NetworkInterface.

Comment: Removing the ethernet cable worked, I am also going to check the documentation to setup everything. Thank you!